# How so send multiple files in MultipartFormDataContent?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api

I wanted to add multiple files to my multi part form data.  I did the following in my WPF client app, but am not sure if this is correct

```
    public string UploadFiles(string type, string[] files)
    {
        string result = string.Empty;

        string url = "http://localhost/api/Utilities/Upload/" + type;

        MultipartFormDataContent form = new MultipartFormDataContent();
        form.Add(new StringContent("value"), "category");
        form.Add(new StringContent("value"), "source");
        form.Add(new StringContent("value"), "enteredby");
        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            var fileContent = new StreamContent(fileStream);
            fileContent.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
        }

        var response = client.PostAsync(url, form);

        return result;
    }
```

And in my ASP>NET Web Api controller I read the content like this

```
        string source = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Form.Get("source");
        string category = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Form.Get("category");
        string enteredby = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Form.Get("enteredby");

        System.Web.HttpFileCollection hfc = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files;
```

I can get the first thee values, but how do I get the files I added?
Also is there a way to include the files in the form so they are accessible from `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont see that you have actually added the 'StreamContent' to the 'form' variable you have created. Inside your for-loop, write :  -

```
FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
var fileContent = new StreamContent(fileStream);
fileContent.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
form.Add(fileContent);
```